# How do I upload video of combination of different match cricket clip to YouTube without Copy-right

Tags: video-editor, youtube, copyright

I want to upload some best interesting facts by combining different match clips.
Example best catches, abnormal out, best spin, etc.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question unless you give us a bit more detail — who shot the clips in question?

Comment: I want to mix the clip of old & new cricket match to highlight some of the best catches or stumping etc., or may to highlight top performance of any player